# How do i add element from one list into another list?

Tags: python, list, file, indexing

I am trying to create a new list from the 4th element of preexisting lists that are read in from a text file in order to get the sum of all elements.
This is what I currently have, but I can't get it working.

```
mainlist = []
newlist = []
openfile = open('filename.txt', 'r')

for line in openfile:
    line = line.rstrip().split()
    mainlist.append(line)

for i in mainlist:
    newlist.append(mainlist[i][4])
```

I am a complete novice so any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: What language are you using?

Comment: Python. Sorry should have specified

Comment: Variable and function names should follow the `lower_case_with_underscores` style. I suggest using a context manager to handle files.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here we are

```
with  open('source.txt', 'r') as openfile:
    mainlist = [line.rstrip().split(', ') for line in openfile]
    newlist = [item[3:] for item in mainlist]

    print(newlist)
```

Outputs

```
['30', '34', '80']
```

### In case you want all "counts" from the third column

```
openfile = open('source.txt', 'r')

mainlist = [line.rstrip().split(', ') for line in openfile]
newlist = [item[3:] for item in mainlist]

print(newlist)
```

Outputs

```
[['30', '30', '30'], ['34', '32', '23'], ['80', '30', '32']]
```

Comment: Thank You! However i'm not getting an error saying 'IndexError: list index out of range' and there are 5 elements in each list. Is there an easy fix for this?

Comment: the 4th element has index `3`. Indexes in python start from zero.

Comment: I'm aware indexes start at 0. Would the problem be with the way the text file is formatted in that case?

Comment: can you attach your file content?

Comment: @AlexandrShurigin I suggest using `newlist = [item[3] for item in mainlist]` for more efficiency.

Comment: of course that's better but now I am trying to understand what we have and want :)

Comment: 08:00, Breakfast, Coffee, 30, 30, 30
08:00, Breakfast, Toast, 34, 32, 23
12:30, Lunch, Sandwich, 80, 30, 32

Comment: @mcveigh437 edit your question properly so it includes all the information we need. 
What's in your text file? What is your current output? What output do you expect? What errors do you see? etc.

Comment: @AlexandrShurigin so i'm trying to get the information from this text file into a list, then from that list i want to take the 5th element from each and put them into their own list so i can perform a sum!

Comment: Seems fine to me, I'll have the coffee first too, but please not at eight, it's Sunday.

Comment: @AlexandrShurigin Thanks for the help, however i'm still getting the error:

Comment: what is the error? have you checked my eduted answer? For me all works fine

Comment: You’re not closing the file? You should just use a context manager, it keeps thing simple and safe.

Comment: good catch, but not a fault when you are reading files :D in the script end it will be closed by Python anyway. But let me update the source code